# What is the total circuit impedance of a parallel LC (6.8mH and 0.1uF) in series with a 1.2kOhm resistor, at 2.5kHz?

Tags: capacitor, resistors, ac, inductor

This is not homework and I've really tried to get an answer, unfortunately, I can't seem to understand what's going on.

Basically, I tried to do the impedance of \$LC\$ (so, \$z=[(\omega C)-1/\omega L]^{-1}\$. Then I tried to get the impedance for the resistor, but I got stuck. After looking online, I tried to do \$1/C \times (\omega/[\omega-(1/\sqrt{LC})]^2\$ because I found it somewhere. Again, no idea what to do with the \$R\$.

Comment: Also, please describe what you did don't just present the result. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Describe what **you** did first.

Comment: Basically, I tried to do the impedance of LC (so, z=[(w*C)-1/wL]^-1. Then I tried to get the impedance for the resistor, but I got stuck. 

after looking online, I tried to do 1/C*(w/[w-(1/square root of L*C)]^2 because I found it somewhere. Again, no idea what to do with the R. To make it worse, I don't know the solution for this problem. Thanks!

Comment: I've edited the description of your attempt into your question. Please include this information from the beginning in the future.

Comment: You can't solve an parallel LC like that becuase the L and C interact with eachother especially near the resonance frequency. If you want an analytical solution you HAVE to use the imaginary j in the formulas. That's tricky so I use a shortcut, see my answer.

Comment: The procedure is the same as it would be if you were dealing with three resistors; but the devil's in the detail, as you cannot simply represent the L and C using their ohmic reactance values. You must represent the reactances in imaginary number form since this is the best way of taking phase angle into account. Alternatively, you could proceed by phasor diagram, which gives a geometric representation and avoids complex numbers. But, whilst this is educationally valuable, it becomes unwieldy when the circuit contains more than a (very small) handful of components.

Answer (score 4):

This answer is not for the purists: -

> why do I need to use j?

There is a good reason and that is because, in an inductor the instantaneous ratio of voltage and current (impedance) is just NOT a constant value like it is in a resistor. This means you have to use a frig-factor (purists will hate me calling it that of course). The frig factor is "j" but first, remind yourself about inductor and capacitor current and voltage waveforms when sine waves are used: -

[image]

And for a resistor it is: -

[image]

To be able to express the ratio of voltage and current (in a capacitor) as a ratio, you multiply the current by "j" and, in doing so, you have correctly shifted the current by 90 degrees. This is really important; multiplying a sinewave by j shifts it 90 degrees. Multiplying something by \$j^2\$ is the same as shifting it by 180 degrees which happens to be the same as multiplying a number by -1. OK so far?

So, the current in a capacitor (compared to it's voltage) is multiplied by j to signify that it leads the voltage by 90 degrees. For an inductor, it follows that the current is "marked" with -j to signify it lags the voltage by 90 degrees.

Incidentally, if \$j^2\$ = -1 then it has to follow that \$j^3\$ = -j and if you did some algebra you would find that j = \$\sqrt{-1}\$. You might have heard this mentioned somewhere?

It also quite simply follows that \$ -j = \dfrac{1}{j}\$ (I'll be using this below)...

So, back the the impedance problem. The parallel combination of C and L have to be treated as proper complex numbers to do the math justice and the impedance is of course product divided by sum: -

Z = \$\dfrac{\frac{1}{jwC}\times\frac{wL}{-j}}{\frac{1}{jwC}+\frac{wL}{-j}}\$ = \$\dfrac{jwL}{1+ j^2w^2LC}\$ = \$\dfrac{jwL}{1- w^2LC}\$

Of note here is the denominator; when \$w^2LC = 1\$ the impedance is infinite.

Or, put another way, resonance occurs when \$w = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{LC}}\$ or \$F_{RES} = \dfrac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{LC}}\$.

Anyway that's the impedance of the parallel combo of L and C and, if you put a resistor in series the impedance becomes: -

Impedance = \$ R + \dfrac{jwL}{1- w^2LC}\$

I suspect this isn't going to help much because you haven't grasped the concept of "j" but keep plugging at it and "ask"!

Answer (score 1):

This is my back-of-an-envelope / practical approach:

A parallel LC resonates at \$Fc = 1/(2\pi * \sqrt{LC } )\$ , in this case 6.1 kHz. We want to know the impedance at a lower frequency 2.5 kHz. That should be far enough from the resonance frequency to assume that most of the impedance is due to the inductor, the impedance of the capacitor will be significantly higher (and above Fc it will be the other way round). So the inductor's impedance will be: \$Zl = jwL = j 2\pi f L\$, here 106j.

Put the R in series: \$1200 + 106 j\$ ohms

Note that this is an approximation (as a result of leaving out the capacitor)
, see other answer for more precise result.

Comment: and that's the final answer? why do I need to use j?

Comment: If you need to ask that then you need to study network theory my friend. It is needed to express the true behaviour of reactive elements like capacitors and inductors. In resistors current and voltage are always directly in sync with eachother, in capacitors and inductors they are not. The j is used to describe this.

Comment: You might notice that it's a complex number, so in addition to having a magnitude, it also has a phase angle. A purely resistive network (no j) will just change the magnitude, a reactive network will also affect the phase.

Comment: @FakeMoustache: or he needs to read just https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_impedance#Complex_impedance All his question is basically what impedance is.

Comment: @JayKeegan: [This](http://bit.ly/1QhWRX9) is less typing (and clearer).

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I learned to do it in school, I think it's right but that was a while ago.

[image]

Here is the ["save time"](http://bit.ly/1QhWRX9) part (you need to use *i* rather than *j* there because Wolfram Alpha is a math program and *i* rather than *j* is the math notation for the complex unit)
[image]